# Javascript Search Nested Object with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, json, object, nested

I have this:

```
var foo = {
          "Category1": [
            {"Company1": {"URL": ["DomainName1", "DomainName2"]}},
            ...
          ],
          ...
          }
```

Normally, I would access the DomainName1 like this:

```
foo["Category1"][0]["Company1"]["URL"][0]
```

However, I want to search all of `foo` for a certain DomainName, and I don't know any other information. I know that I could use several nested for loops, but that is *very, very* slow. What is an efficient way to do this? I was thinking of something along the lines of a `'*'` in place of `["Category1"]`, `[0]`, etc. but I don't know how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big is your `foo` object? Is the tree a fixed structure or amount of nested levels can very? What are you exactly search for: URL value or the "address" to it inside `foo`? What does _Very-very slow_ mean? How fast would like it to be? From your words I suppose you haven't tried a recursive solution...

Comment: So what do you want, a reference to the category, company or url?

Comment: *"I know that I could use several nested for loops, but that is very, very slow."* I assume that means that you tried this approach? Why do you need several nested loops? Is the structure of `foo` irregular? It looks like you need at most three loops.

Comment: @KirillSlatin It's quite long, with tens of thousands of properties.

Comment: @RobG Reference to company

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, but since `foo` is actually really, really big it becomes very slow

Comment: You might want to restructure the data then so that search becomes more performant. E.g. `[[url, [company, ...], ...]` (sorted) and perform a binary search.

Comment: I think writing a regex is going to be quite a task and may not perform any better than looping

Comment: @FelixKling With thousands of entries, how would I do that (other than doing it manually)?

Comment: Well, you still have to iterate over the data and build the new structure, but you only have to do this once. Searches after that will be faster. It all depends on the use case though.

Comment: As Felix says, if the data doesn't change much, it's likely best to build an index and use that. I'd use an object like: `{url1: [company1, company2], url2: [comany3, company4],...}` where *company* is a reference to the related company object or the name as a string, whatever suits.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good problem to solve it using [Jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

For instance, you can use this expression to look for all URL:

```
var out = jsonPath(json, "$..URL[*]").toJSONString() + "\n";
document.write(out);
```

You can use an expression to match the domain you want.

For your case, you can use this expression:

```
$..URL[?(@.indexOf('DomainName1') != -1)]
```

**[Jsonpath online tool](http://www.jsonquerytool.com/sample/jsonpathfilterbyarraycontents)**

Here is a useful Jsonpath example from the **[documentation](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/Javascript)**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> JSONPath - Example (js)</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsonpath.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var json = 
                  { "store": {
                        "book": [ 
                          { "category": "reference",
                                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                                "price": 8.95
                          },
                          { "category": "fiction",
                                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                                "price": 12.99
                          },
                          { "category": "fiction",
                                "author": "Herman Melville",
                                "title": "Moby Dick",
                                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                                "price": 8.99
                          },
                          { "category": "fiction",
                                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                                "price": 22.99
                          }
                        ],
                        "bicycle": {
                          "color": "red",
                          "price": 19.95
                        }
                  }
                },
           out = "";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$.store.book[*].author").toJSONString() + "\n>";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$..author").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$.store.*").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$.store..price").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$..book[(@.length-1)]").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$..book[-1:]").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$..book[0,1]").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$..book[:2]").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$..book[?(@.isbn)]").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$..book[?(@.price<10)]").toJSONString() + "\n";
       out += jsonPath(json, "$..*").toJSONString() + "\n";
       document.write(out);
  </script>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Example output:

```
["Nigel Rees","Evelyn Waugh","Herman Melville","J. R. R. Tolkien"]
["Nigel Rees","Evelyn Waugh","Herman Melville","J. R. R. Tolkien"]
[[{"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95},{"category":"fiction","author":"Evelyn Waugh","title":"Sword of Honour","price":12.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"Herman Melville","title":"Moby Dick","isbn":"0-553-21311-3","price":8.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien","title":"The Lord of the Rings","isbn":"0-395-19395-8","price":22.99}],{"color":"red","price":19.95}]
[8.95,12.99,8.99,22.99,19.95]
[{"category":"fiction","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien","title":"The Lord of the Rings","isbn":"0-395-19395-8","price":22.99}]
[{"category":"fiction","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien","title":"The Lord of the Rings","isbn":"0-395-19395-8","price":22.99}]
[{"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95},{"category":"fiction","author":"Evelyn Waugh","title":"Sword of Honour","price":12.99}]
[{"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95},{"category":"fiction","author":"Evelyn Waugh","title":"Sword of Honour","price":12.99}]
[{"category":"fiction","author":"Herman Melville","title":"Moby Dick","isbn":"0-553-21311-3","price":8.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien","title":"The Lord of the Rings","isbn":"0-395-19395-8","price":22.99}]
[{"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95},{"category":"fiction","author":"Herman Melville","title":"Moby Dick","isbn":"0-553-21311-3","price":8.99}]
[{"book":[{"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95},{"category":"fiction","author":"Evelyn Waugh","title":"Sword of Honour","price":12.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"Herman Melville","title":"Moby Dick","isbn":"0-553-21311-3","price":8.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien","title":"The Lord of the Rings","isbn":"0-395-19395-8","price":22.99}],"bicycle":{"color":"red","price":19.95}},[{"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95},{"category":"fiction","author":"Evelyn Waugh","title":"Sword of Honour","price":12.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"Herman Melville","title":"Moby Dick","isbn":"0-553-21311-3","price":8.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien","title":"The Lord of the Rings","isbn":"0-395-19395-8","price":22.99}],{"color":"red","price":19.95},{"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95},{"category":"fiction","author":"Evelyn Waugh","title":"Sword of Honour","price":12.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"Herman Melville","title":"Moby Dick","isbn":"0-553-21311-3","price":8.99},{"category":"fiction","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien","title":"The Lord of the Rings","isbn":"0-395-19395-8","price":22.99},"reference","Nigel Rees","Sayings of the Century",8.95,"fiction","Evelyn Waugh","Sword of Honour",12.99,"fiction","Herman Melville","Moby Dick","0-553-21311-3",8.99,"fiction","J. R. R. Tolkien","The Lord of the Rings","0-395-19395-8",22.99,"red",19.95]
```

Just use the expression you want to easily query your json structure.

Comment: I wonder how this is going to be faster than iterating properties directly with pure javascript...

Comment: @KirillSlatin jsonpath is the tool to filter large json, why reinventing the wheel when there is already a tool to help with json queries...

Comment: All those `+=` are going to be really slow.

Comment: The question is not about `+=`... Regular expression parsing will give an overhead, that's for sure. And there is no algorithm improvement, just syntax sugar.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be opinionated however still... With *tens of thousands* objects you're trying to re-invent the wheel. This is an exact candidate for a database storage. Either SQL or non-SQL like MongoDB.